# how to use crop filter twice in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to use crop filter in two different locations, for example top left + bottom right and to merge them, how can I do this?

I want to use the code once, not to make with two independent crops and merge after that.

EDIT: an image: http://alexvorn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ffmpeg-multiple-crop.png

Comment: What do you mean by "merge them"? Perhaps a visual representation with some images of what you want will make it easier to provide a command.

Comment: sure! - http://alexvorn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ffmpeg-multiple-crop.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: original]
[image: result]
<sub>Original and resulting images.</sub>

The [`crop`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) and [`hstack`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) video filters in ffmpeg will achieve this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:0]crop=iw/2:ih/2:0:0[tl]; \
 [0:0]crop=iw/2:ih/2:iw/2:ih/2[br]; \
 [tl][br]hstack=inputs=2" \
-codec:a copy output.mp4
```

See the [`vstack`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack) filter if you prefer vertical stacking instead of horizontal stacking.